# Devise invitable upgrade after_invite_path_for has different resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise-invitable

I recently upgraded to devise_invitable 1.5.1.

Previously I was overwriting the after_invite_path_for method in my

`class InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController` controller

I wanted to send the inviter to a path created based on the invitee so I was using

```
permissions_path(resource)
```

but now, with the new version, the resource actually represents the inviter, whereas before it was the invitee.

How do I get the invitee in this method so I can retrieve the right path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user details are available in params[:user]

```
permissions_path(User.find_by_email! params[:user][:email])
```